# TypeError when importing json data with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to import json data from a link containing valid json data to MongoDB.
When I run the script I get the following error:

> TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

What am I missing here or doing wrong?

```
import pymongo
import urllib.parse
import requests

replay_url = "http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?"

userid = 769630584166547456

url2 = replay_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({'userid': userid}) + '&page_size=1000'

print(f"Replay url: {url2}")

raw_replay_data = requests.get(url2).json()

uri = 'mongodb://testuser:password@ds245687.mlab.com:45687/liveme'

client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

db = client.get_default_database()

replays = db['replays']

replays.insert_many(raw_replay_data)

client.close()
```

Comment: check your `raw_replay_data` try to convert in it dictionary then try to save it

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi Can you give me a hint how to do that? :)

Comment: `insert_many` accepts a list of dictionaries. I guess your `raw_replay_data` is a dictionary. use `insert_one` and check the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you are getting the video information data for 22 videos.

You can use :

```
replays.insert_many(raw_replay_data['data']['video_info'])
```

for saving them

Comment: When I run it twice I get duplicate entries. Can you help me with how I don't insert already existing videos, but only add new videos. Make it skip already inserted entires.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one field as `_id` for mongodb document

use the following line before `insert_many`

```
for i in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    i['_id'] = i['vid']
```

this will make the 'vid' field as your '_id'. Just make sure that the 'vid' is unique for all videos.